# react child component doesn't respond to click event

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I'm having an issue with the component not firing a **click** event on *button* **click**.

### TickerPage

```
render() {
  return (
    <div className="TickerPage">
      <div className="TickerPage-container">
        <br />

        <div className='leftContainer'>
          <PlayersTable players={this.state.players} />
        </div>

        <div className='rightContainer'>
          <PlayerDetail playerid={this.state.playerid} />
        </div>

        <div className='bottomTicker'>
          <Ticker />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
```

### PlayersTable

```
render() {
  let tbl = this.buildTable();

  return (
    <div className="PlayersTable">
      <div className="PlayersTable-container">

        <button onclick='alert("test")'>test</button>

        <h1 className='heading'>Players</h1>
        {tbl}
        <br />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

When I click the button on the `PlayersTable`, nothing happens. It should have an alert box.

Thanks!

Comment: Try this https://jsfiddle.net/_alexander_/69z2wepo/23383/. In this case you should use `{ }` instead of `' '`, also you need pass to `onClick` reference to function not function itself, you can do it with ES6 arrow functions like this, `onClick={ () => alert(1) }`

Comment: this doesn't work for some reason. it doesn't work if I put a button in the main page either

Answer (score 1):

The reason it does not work in your case it is is expected to be a function reference.

The best way to assign the click event is to do it in the `createClass` method.

**JS**

```
 <button onClick={this.handleClick}>test</button>

   handleClick: function(event) {
      alert("test")
    },
```

I would personally avoid including the function definition in inline HTML.

Answer (score 0):

the issue is I had onclick and not onClick

Thanks!